# Can't get Grid Panel to Translate Transform XProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new to WPF, and I get error everytime I run my code

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
TranslateTransform tt = (OPMenuScreen.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[0] as TranslateTransform;

da.By = -250;
tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, da);
```

Why can't I get OPMenuScreen to move to a -250 Xproperty for TranslateTransform?

Comment: @Ben Robinson: I get this error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - on the TranslateTransform tt line

Comment: As @BenRobinson suggests, this is most likely because the `OPMenuScreen.RenderTransform` is not a `TransformGroup` instance.  When you step through the code, what is the value of that property?

Comment: @Steve According to BenRobinson, I have a null children. But how do I make Children?

Comment: @Corbee I don't think that `Children` *can* be null, though I'm not certain.  See my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from comments...

I'm not sure that the `Children` property is null in your example - I think it's more likely that either your `RenderTransform` is null or it is not an instance of `TransformGroup`.  Either way, you should just need to make sure that you have the following specified in your XAML:

Note: I have no idea what type `OPMenuScreen` is, so I'll use `Control` for the example

```
<Control ...>
    <Control.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Control.RenderTransform>
</Control>
```

Comment: Your right! I had no idea that adding those codes in XAML is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK then nif you are getting a null ref exception then it is probably caused by this line

```
TranslateTransform tt = (OPMenuScreen.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
```

Which probably means that element 0 of the Children property does not exist because Children is null.

Comment: :If that's the case, how do I assign OPMenuScreen to TranslateTransform, so that it could animate a decrement of -250 everytime the method is called?